# How to locate pagination out of ul tag in listview

Tags: listview, pagination, yii2

While making Yii2 website I met some difficulties with listview widget. My frontend-developer says that pagination container should be out of items container. Here is my code.

```
<?php echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
          'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
          'pager'=>[
                 'hideOnSinglePage'=>true,
                 // Customzing options for pager container tag
                 'options' => [
                        'class' => 'pager-wrapper',
                        'id' => 'pager-container',
                 ],
            ],
            'itemView'=>'_item',
            'summary' => '',
            'itemOptions' => ['tag'=>'li', 'class'=>'cam-container'],
            'options' => [
                'tag'=>'ul', 
                'class'=>'cam-list row clearfix'
            ]
])?>
```

and this listview widget generates this code in HTML

```
<ul id="w0" class="cam-list row clearfix">
       <li class="cam-container" data-key="34"></li>
       <ul id="pager-container" class="pager-wrapper">
 </ul>
```

But I want the result where `pager-container` will be out of the `.cam-list` container

```
 <ul id="w0" class="cam-list row clearfix">
       <li class="cam-container" data-key="34"></li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="pager-container" class="pager-wrapper">
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found that we can render them separately. In my case I render them like

```
$widget = \yii\widgets\ListView::begin([ some code ]);

<ul class="cam-list row clearfix">
    <?php echo $widget->renderItems();  ?>
</ul>
<?php echo $widget->renderPager(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution for my application:

```
<?php echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
          'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
          'pager'=>[
                 'hideOnSinglePage'=>true,
                 // Customzing options for pager container tag
                 'options' => [
                        'class' => 'pager-wrapper',
                        'id' => 'pager-container',
                 ],
            ],
            'itemView'=>'_item',
            'summary' => '',
            'layout' => "{summary}\n<ul class='cam-list row clearfix'>{items}</ul>\n{pager}",
            'itemOptions' => ['tag'=>'li', 'class'=>'cam-container'],
])?>
```

for this solution I use layout for adding `<ul>` around items and render pager after it.